# Small wireless transmitter and receiver

Tags: rf, bluetooth, transmitter, receiver

I am looking for suggestions for wireless transmitter/receiver chips/circuitry. I have the following system in mind:

- Multiple transmitters to one receiver
  Transmitters do not have access to microcontroller and have to run off batteries that can only supply a few mAmp.
- Bi-directional communication not a must, but a nice to have
- I only need to send a byte or two of data to and from
- System needs to be as miniature as possible, thus SMD IC's and chips are a must
- System requires 50m or more transmission range

I have developed a solution that uses simple 433MHz transmitters with HT12 encoders and the corresponding receiver system on the other side. The downfall of this system is that while one transmitter is transmitting it will jam any other transmitter, and its one directional.

Does anyone have suggestions for the above? Bluetooth, BLE, RF, etc?

Comment: Hi Misha! Nice having you here. However, your first sentence reads like you're looking for product recommendations, which are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: If the TX side doesn't have a controller, how do you control when data is sent?

Comment: Can you post a schematic of your present system?

Comment: Take a look at RFID it may do what you want.

Comment: If the TX side can't receive, it also can't be told when to transmit, leaving you with the problem of it having to always be ON and always transmitting, at least at some minimum frequency.  For a low power device this seems a significant problem.

Comment: @Marcus, I am not looking for a product, I am looking for suggestions and direction regarding what components are used in industry.

Comment: @Aaron, depending on your system, a simple logic encoder, like HT12-E, can easily be used with some basic switching circuitry to do what is needed in a low power, microcontroller less way. I have followed the basic guidelines as described in the HT12-E and HT12-D datasheet for schematic.

Comment: @Gil, thank you for your suggestion. Do you by any change have some slightly more specific than just RFID? Lots of different RFID implementations?

Comment: @KH, you hit the nail on the head. There are some BLE chips and applications that apparently can do this. But I have not found actual components.

Comment: @KH least power sensors actually prefer that, as for low-duty cycle networks, fire-forget-repeat-twice is lower in energy requirements than listening for request continuously (by orders of magnitudes!)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I thought about that but OP wants multiple simultaneous devices, so I was thinking it would be a problem if two of them synced up.

Comment: @KH typically solved through mandatory randomized intervals!

Answer (score 1):

> Transmitters do not have access to microcontroller

Without some kind of brains behind the transmitter, "collisions" are guaranteed.  ((All)) multi-user environments, from old party-line telephone systems to 5G, require brains behind the transmitter to recognize and recover from whatever form of collision/over-talking/garbled transmission that has taken place.  A key requirement for this is that each transmitter must have a receiver, either to be told when to transmit, to to be told to re-transmit the last message.

Examples of those two options are more popularly know as ARCnet (a form of token ring) and Ethernet (CSMA/CD - the CD stands for collision detection).  You don't need anything that complex for a small, low speed, dedicated system.  But note that Bluetooth and BLE both are bi-directional systems with collision handling built into their communication protocols.